# В какой книге описывается конструкция partition by

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, книги

Дело не в том что я не могу прочитать об этом в интернете, просто хочется прочитать хорошую книгу, где описываются большинство конструкций?

Comment: Начнем с того что в MySQL в принципе нет оконных функций и конструкции "partition by". Для остальных СУБД они немного различаются. И почему обязательно книга, я например ни одной книги по SQL в руках вообще не держал. тема оконных функций небольшая, по ссылкам гугл по запросу "SQL оконные функции" можно быстро понять что к чему

Comment: Собственно вот тут https://habrahabr.ru/post/268983/ описано достаточно толково (хотя сильно не вчитывался). Это postgres, но он похож очень на oracle, только в оракле вроде явного объявления окна (предложение window) нет.

Answer (score 1):

Том Кайт Oracle для профессионалов, радел про аналитические функции.
по MySql ничего не подскажу

Comment: По моему в вопросе идет речь о "partition by" в предложении "over" SQL, т.е. в оконных функциях. А вы говорите про разделение таблиц на разделы.

Comment: Хм, справедливо. Тогда точно Кайт